# Firebase security rules "false for list" error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a "courses" resource with different levels of access allowed to it.

I have setup the following rules for it:

```
      allow read: 
      if
      isSuperAdmin() ||
      adminBelongsToWorkSpace(workspaceId) ||
      editorBelongsToWorkSpace(workspaceId) || 
      (canView(resource) || canEdit(resource)) && belongsToWorkspace(workspaceId) ||
      allCanView(resource) && belongsToWorkspace(workspaceId) ||
      isPublicAccess(resource) && isPublished(resource);
```

The access levels basically dictate:

- Can access if you are a super admin
- Can access if you are an admin and belong to the workspace (all courses are under a workspace)
- Can access if you are an editor and belong to the workspace
- Can access if you your UID is inside an array "canView" OR "canEdit" and you belong to the workspace
- Can access if the course is public access and is published. (Meaning unauthenticated users)

The way I build the query is this:

```
const ref = firestore
    .collection('workspaces')
    .doc(workspaceId)
    .collection('courses');


let courses;
let data;

try {
    
    if (getAll) {
        data = await ref.get();
        
    } else {
        if (publicAccess) {
            ref.where('publicAccess', '==', true);
            ref.where('published', '==', true);
            
        }

        if (allCanView) {
            ref.where('published', '==', true);
            ref.where('allCanView', '==', true);
            
        }

        if (userId) {
            ref.where('published', '==', true);
            ref.where('allCanView', '==', true);
            ref.where('canView', 'array-contains', userId);
            ref.where('canEdit', 'array-contains', userId);
        
        }

        data = await ref.get();
    }
```

You can see that the documents I query are conditional upon boolean values such as publicAccess, allCanView and UserId (string). GetAll boolean is used in case the editor/admin/superadmin is trying to query, in which case you get everything.

In the console I get this error, and I don't know how to process it:

```
FirebaseError: 
false for 'list' @ L103
```

L103 - line 103, points to "isSuperAdmin()", and this function is the following:

```
  function isSuperAdmin() {
    return isSignedIn() && request.auth.token.superadmin == true;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested the rules out on the rules playground and they work fine for fetching the data. So I am guessing it's the queries and how they're constructed that is the issue.

The error occurs when the user is not an admin, just a user, but has his ID in the canView/canEdit arrays.

But as far as I know this is correct:

```
            ref.where('canView', 'array-contains', userId);
            ref.where('canEdit', 'array-contains', userId);
```

Comment: Could you please share the whole set of Rules so that it's possible to see other functions like `adminBelongsToWorkSpace`, `editorBelongsToWorkSpace`, etc?